# Django Rest Framework says No input provided?

Tags: django, curl, django-rest-framework

I want to make it so that I can upload files and text to my server endpoint.

Here's an example post from curl that I want to have work:

```
curl -X POST https://mydomain.com/myapp/ -u user:pass -F "body=test" -F "eyecon.png=@/Users/myaccount/myproject/eyecon.png"
```

The problem is, when I run this, I get this error message:

```
{"non_field_errors": ["No input provided"]}
```

I looked through the Django Rest Framework code and it only generates this error message from a single location, which is for handling the case when `request.DATA` and `request.FILES` are both empty/missing. So I suspect that my issue is somewhere in a configuration file (could be Apache, Django, or Django Rest Kit's configuration that I messed up). I expect someone will tell me that there's a single line I'm missing somewhere and it'll be a quick and easy fix.

But just incase it isn't a configuration issue and it's actually an issue with my code, here's all of my code related to this:

**views.py**

```
class MessageList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    queryset           = Message.objects.all()
    serializer_class   = MessageSerializer

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.owner = self.request.user
```

**serializers.py**

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.username')

    def __init__(self, instance=None, data=None, files=None,
                 context=None, partial=False, many=None,
                 allow_add_remove=False, **kwargs):
        super(MessageSerializer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for attachment in files.getlist('file', []):
            Attachment(target=id, file=attachment).save()

    class Meta:
        model  = Message
        fields = ('id', 'owner', 'title', 'created', 'body')
```

**models.py**

```
class Message(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    body    = models.TextField()
    owner   = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='messages')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

class Attachment(models.Model):
    target  = models.ForeignKey('server_app.Message', related_name='attachments')
    theFile = models.FileField(upload_to='attachments/')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was in serializers.py. When I call `super(...).__init__(**kwargs)`, I neglected to pass in all the other arguments that were received. Thus the serializer complained about not getting input because I wasn't giving it input.

Corrected it by replacing my prior call to `super(...).__init__(...)` with:

```
super(MessageSerializer, self).__init__(self, instance=instance, data=data, files=files,
                                        context=context, partial=partial, many=many,
                                        allow_add_remove=allow_add_remove, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Don't you want to use the arguments supplied to MessageSerializer rather than reusing the default ones while also omitting 'self'? Like so: super(MessageSerializer, self).__init__(instance, data, files, context, partial, many, allow_add_remove, **kwargs)

Comment: @user640916 - Yes, you're right. This isn't the actual code in my project (which is covered by NDA). In my anonymizing process I accidentally wrote code which doesn't make much sense. I have edited my answer to fix that.